# Why do my "to path" arrowheads disappear when I upgrade to PGF 2.10?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, pgf-core

Since I upgraded to PGF 2.10, some of my arrows drawn with `to` don't look right anymore. For instance, they are missing arrow-heads, and some other styles I applied to them have also disappeared. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[->, line width=2mm] (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I'm not getting any error messages nor anything relevant in the log file. This example compiles correctly with PGF 2.00.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since PGF 2.10, arguments modifying path style no longer work when you put them after the `to` keyword. They should be put directly after the `\draw` command. Like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, line width=2mm] (0,0) to (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

All in all, this took me weeks to find out. For quite a while, I even downgraded to PGF 2.00 because my arrows didn't work.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in PGF 2.10 or if I was **never meant** to put these properties on `to`, and PGF 2.10 fixed the mistake. However, in the latter case, I would have expected an error message.

In any case, I advice you not to worry about it and just put these sorts of properties on `\draw`, which always seems to work.

If anyone has more information about this phenomenon, I'd be very interested!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `to` path didn't have any options before so that's why TikZ could understand the options for example this also works : `\draw (0,0) to (3,1) [->, line width=2mm];` So if it's not ambiguous, TikZ is smart enough to see that options are coming in, but here `to` also looks for extra options that are not necessarily related to the path drawing, hence the conflict. So it cannot throw errors since the code is legitimate.

Comment: Hm... No, `to` had options before, like `in` and `out`. That's basically the reason I was using `to` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I didn't recall correctly. This is from the changelog by T.Tantau *Changed scoping rules for to path operation: Options are now local. This may break existing code, but is much more
consistent with everything else and removes other problems.*

Comment: Ah, I finally have a definitive explanation. Thanks! :-)

Comment: But then.. wouldn't it make sense to get at least a warning when you provide options that make no local sense?

Comment: I think that would be a huge task since you have to classify what is locally effective and what is not. Especially if you are using custom styles such as `..to[mystyle]` it gets quickly out of hand Besides you can use some of the keys both locally and globally .

Comment: Well, I won't go into language/library design with you. ;-) I feel like it wouldn't be so hard to detect whether a command had any effect or not, theoretically. But I don't know enough about the guts of TeX and PGF to make that judgment. Thanks for your answer! Let's close this discussion.