# Why can't I apply this decoration to a curve produced using the "to" path operation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I have found that I cannot make decorations apply to (most) curves drawn using the "to" path operation. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, topaths}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{nomorepostaction/.code = \let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother
\tikzset{bigdiagramarrow/.style = {
    decoration = {markings, mark = at position 1 with {\arrow[thick]{latex}}},
    postaction = {nomorepostaction, decorate}
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {$A$};
        \node [draw] (B) at (0, 1) {$B$};
        \node [draw] (C) at (2, 1) {$C$};
        \draw [bigdiagramarrow] (A) -- (B);
        \draw [out = 0, in = 180, bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get when I compile it:

[image]

As you can see, an arrowhead is drawn on the end of the path drawn using the `--` path operation, but no arrowhead is drawn on the end of the path drawn using the `to` path operation.

Strangely, in the document in which I encountered this issue, I found that some curves created using the "to" path operation will display the decoration. To be more precise, 3 of the 12 curves in the document I am actually trying to typeset display the decoration. It is the same 3 every time I compile the document. I do not know what sets these 3 apart from the rest.

At first it appeared that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71378/why-do-my-to-path-arrowheads-disappear-when-i-upgrade-to-pgf-2-10) might be relevant, but I do not appear to be encountering the same "gotcha" so far as I can see, since I am not passing options to the `to` path operation but rather to the `\draw` macro.

NB. The `nomorepostaction` key comes from Ulrich Schwarz's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz).

Comment: It works with `at position .9999`.

Comment: `\draw (A)` and `(A) to (C)` are two distinct paths. So you are not doing anything to the `to` path as it is.

Comment: Related: [TikZ: Bug with multiple decorations “at position 1”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50534/tikz-bug-with-multiple-decorations-at-position-1)

Comment: @percusse And `\draw [bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (B);`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The same

Comment: @percusse I got an arrowhead with `(A) to (B)`. Or `\draw [out = 0, in = 206, bigdiagramarrow] (A) to + (0:2);` (but not with `out=207`). I do not see any relation to two to paths.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah yes, I wasn't clear. I was confirming OPs remark that same gotcha indeed doesn't apply. But usually this comes from the `skipper` step of the `markings` decoration inaccuracy.

Comment: I couldn't find the other bug report but sometimes `markings` also suffer from this http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3496004&group_id=142562&atid=752792

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found two more or less appropriate ways to change the arrow size (which is not a solution of the actual problem at hand, namely that `at position 1` is not *calculated* correct):

- *less appropriate:*

  - New arrow head: `_latex`
  - New style: `arrow line width` that takes a **length** (the new `\pgflinewidth`)
  - and `arrow ultra thin`, `arrow very thin`, …, `arrow ultra thick` that set `arrow line width`
- *more appropriate:*

  - Re-defining a macro that locally (!) sets a new line width for the arrows.
  - New style: `arrow line width` that takes a **factor**
  - and `arrow ultra thin`, `arrow very thin`, …, `arrow ultra thick` that set `arrow line width`

(They could even be combined.)

## *less appropriate*:  New Arrow Head

I chose to define a new arrow `_latex` that is the same as `latex` only that `\pgflinewidth` is replaced by `\pgflinewidth@arrow`.

The length `\pgflinewidth@arrow` is per default `\pgflinewidth` so the arrow acts as usual unless the key `arrow line width` is used explicitly with an arbitrary length. (Sadly, `thick` and so on cannot be used, *but* `arrow thick`.)

Improvements could be made that one could use the already existing arrows without any change by finding a good hook to set `\pgflinewidth` locally.

For many other way to change the arrow size: [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{nomorepostaction/.code = \let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty}
\newdimen\pgflinewidth@arrow
\pgfarrowsdeclare{_latex}{_latex}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth@arrow%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth@arrow-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-1\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+9\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgflinewidth@arrow%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{.6\pgflinewidth@arrow-.4*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgfutil@tempdimb%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{6.3333\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{2\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1\pgfutil@tempdima}{-3.75\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{6.3333\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\tikzset{
    bigdiagramarrow/.style = {
        -_latex,
        arrow thick
    },
    arrow line width/.code={
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth@arrow{#1}
    },
    arrow line width/.initial=\pgflinewidth,
    arrow ultra thin/.style={arrow line width=0.1pt},
    arrow very thin/.style={arrow line width=0.2pt},
    arrow thin/.style={arrow line width=0.4pt},
    arrow semithick/.style={arrow line width=0.6pt},
    arrow thick/.style={arrow line width=0.8pt},
    arrow very thick/.style={arrow line width=1.2pt},
    arrow ultra thick/.style={arrow line width=1.6pt},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {$A$};
        \node [draw] (B) at (0, 1) {$B$};
        \node [draw] (C) at (2, 1) {$C$};
        \draw [bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (B);
        \draw [out = 0, in = 180][bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## *more appropriate:*

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{nomorepostaction/.code = \let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty}
\def\pgf@arrowset#1#2{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@arrow@code@#2}
  {\PackageError{pgf}{Arrow #1 type ``#2'' unknown}{}}
  {%
    \edef\pgf@arrow@temp{#2}%
    \ifx\pgf@arrow@temp\pgfutil@empty% ah. clear!
      \expandafter\let\csname pgf@#1arrow\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
      \expandafter\let\csname pgf@shorten@#1\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
    \else%
      %\pgf@arrow@prepare{#2}%
      \expandafter\def\csname pgf@#1arrow\endcsname{\multiply\pgflinewidth by \pgflinewidth@arrow\relax\pgf@arrow@call{#2}}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname pgf@shorten@#1\endcsname{\multiply\pgflinewidth by \noexpand\pgflinewidth@arrow\relax\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@arrow@right@#2\endcsname}%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\tikzset{
    bigdiagramarrow/.style = {
        -latex,
        arrow thick
    },
    arrow line width/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgflinewidth@arrow{#1}
    },
    arrow line width=1,
    arrow ultra thin/.style={arrow line width=0.25},
    arrow very thin/.style={arrow line width=0.5},
    arrow thin/.style={arrow line width=1},
    arrow semithick/.style={arrow line width=1.5},
    arrow thick/.style={arrow line width=2},
    arrow very thick/.style={arrow line width=3},
    arrow ultra thick/.style={arrow line width=4},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {$A$};
        \node [draw] (B) at (0, 1) {$B$};
        \node [draw] (C) at (2, 1) {$C$};
        \draw [bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (B);
        \draw [out = 0, in = 180][bigdiagramarrow] (A) to (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your approach of creating a new arrow style proves to be a much more effective way of doing this. With the decorations approach, I was finding that the end of the curve would enter the arrow head askew, which is quite ugly. I am grateful for the effort you appear to have put into this.

Comment: @Hammerite I have updated my answer with a solution I found more fitting, as it doesn’t rely on new arrow heads. (One could even combine both solutions.)

Comment: Your second and preferred method doesn't compile for me. It says `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@shorten@end ...ewidth by \pgflinewidth@arrow <linebreak> \relax \pgf@arrow@right@ti...`

Comment: Wait a minute, if I just copy and paste your code into a file it does compile. but if I put it in the preamble of the document I'm working on I get that error. It must be interfering with something else in the document.

Comment: I worked out what the problem is. If you attempt to use arrow styling without specifying the arrow size, it gets confused.

Comment: I assume the `/.initial` line is supposed to set a default arrow size, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't make it work. If one adds `arrow semithick` to the end of the `tikzset` argument it works.

Comment: @Hammerite Yes, it is supposed to do that. I have corrected both code samples.

Comment: Anyone intending to use this code may wish to also look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147808/1427

Answer (score 6):

Why to adapt a simple way when there are complex methods?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {$A$};
        \node [draw] (B) at (0, 1) {$B$};
        \node [draw] (C) at (2, 1) {$C$};
        \draw [-latex] (A) -- (B);
        \draw [out = 0, in = 180, -latex] (A) to (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]