# Rotate an arrow around its center

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks

I want to draw this with tikz,

[image]

I have been trying to do it with tikz for awhile but didnt get far, with suggestion I moved to PsTricks. This is what I have so far

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\definecolor{DarkOceanSky}{RGB}{133,163,229}
\definecolor{DarkNavyBlue}{RGB}{0,25,63}
\definecolor{Reu}{RGB}{102,173,76}
\definecolor{Crimson}{RGB}{220, 20, 60}

%second part
\def\block{%
        \foreach \x in {1,3,5,...,7}
        {
            \foreach \y in {1,3,5,...,7}
             {%
                \foreach \angle in {0,45,...,315}
                 {
                    \psrline{->}(\x,\y)(!0.10 Rand 1.4 mul add sqrt \angle\space PtoC)
                 }
             }
        }

        \foreach \counter in {0,2,4,6,...,8}
        {
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.8pt}(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.8pt}(0,\counter)(8,\counter)            
        }
        
        \pscircle*[linecolor=Crimson](4,4){0.2}
}



\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](19.0,8)
        %\rput(12,0){\block}
        \rput(11.0,0){\block}
        
        \foreach \counter in {0,2,4,6,...,8}
        {
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.8pt}(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.8pt}(0,\counter)(8,\counter)            
        }
        
        \foreach \counter in {1,3,5,...,7}
        {
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.0pt}(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.0pt}(0, \counter)(8,\counter)
        }
        
        \foreach \counter in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,...,7.5}
        {
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.0pt}(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
            \psline{-, linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=1.0pt}(0, \counter)(8, \counter)
        }

        
        \pscircle[linecolor=Reu](4,4){4.5}
        \pscircle*[linecolor=Crimson](4,4){0.2}
        
        
        %I need to draw those small arrows
        \psrline{->}(1.6, 0.1)(!0.10 Rand 0.3 mul add sqrt 45 PtoC)    
\end{pspicture}
```

\end{document}

[image]

What I need to do now is to create those small arrows on the left figure. They are tiny arrows. I am willing to settle for same size arrows. So basically, fixed-size arrows with different orientations. I think the way to do it is to draw an arrow horizontally and rotate it around the center with random degree. I dont know how to do this and not sure if it is the right way. Can you help me?

Comment: I cannot see clearly what kind of objects are in the little subsquares tot the left? Is there a single arrow on a subsquare?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Yes, they are tiny arrows

Comment: See my updated answer. I have included the complete solution for you. Don't forget to accept it by pressing the check button below the down vote button. Optionally you can up vote it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\definecolor{DarkOceanSky}{RGB}{133,163,229}
\definecolor{DarkNavyBlue}{RGB}{0,25,63}
\definecolor{Reu}{RGB}{102,173,76}
\definecolor{Crimson}{RGB}{220,20,60}

\pstVerb{realtime srand}

\def\Grid{%
    \foreach \counter in {0,2,...,8}{%
        \psset{linecolor=DarkNavyBlue,linewidth=2\pslinewidth,linecap=2}
        \psline(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
        \psline(0,\counter)(8,\counter)          
  }%
}

\def\SubGrid{%
    \foreach \counter in {0,.5,...,8}{%
        \psset{linecolor=DarkOceanSky,linewidth=.5\pslinewidth,linecap=2}
        \psline(\counter,0)(\counter,8)
        \psline(0,\counter)(8,\counter)          
  }%
}

\def\Left{%
    \SubGrid
    \Grid
    \foreach \x in {.25,.75,...,7.75}{%
        \foreach \y in {.25,.75,...,7.75}{%
            \rput{!rand 3601 mod 10 div}(\x,\y){\psline{->}(-4pt,0)(4pt,0)}
        }%
    }%
    \pscircle[linecolor=Reu,linewidth=2\pslinewidth](4,4){4.5}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=Crimson](4,4){0.2}
}

\def\Right{%
    \Grid
    \foreach \x in {1,3,5,...,7}{%
        \foreach \y in {1,3,5,...,7}{%
            \foreach \angle in {0,45,...,315}{%
                \psrline{->}(\x,\y)(!0.10 Rand 1.4 mul add sqrt \angle\space PtoC)
            }%
        }%
    }%
    \pscircle*[linecolor=Crimson](4,4){0.2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](18,9)
    \rput(.5,.5){\Left}
    \rput(10,.5){\Right}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. I cant compile PSTricks with my Miktex yet, but I'll work it out. Could you pleas ehelp me with the first image, I cant create small arrows with tikz.

Comment: @WangZhu: Compile it with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 4):

The placement of the tiny arrows should be optimized (as it is better to be dependent on the grid size and not TikZ’ coordinate system) but here is a two-nested-loops-randomized approach.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\definecolor{DarkOceanSky}{RGB}{133,163,229}
\definecolor{DarkNavyBlue}{RGB}{0,25,63}
\definecolor{Reu}{RGB}{102,173,76}
\definecolor{Crimson}{RGB}{220, 20, 60}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    minorGridStep=.125cm;
    majorGridStep=.5cm;
  },
  major grid/.style={
    line width=+.018cm,
    draw=DarkNavyBlue,
    step=majorGridStep,
  },
  minor grid/.style={
    line width=+.008cm,
    draw=DarkNavyBlue,
    step=minorGridStep
  },
  green circle/.style={
    draw=Reu,
    radius=1.1,
    line width=+.008cm
  },
  red dot/.style={
    fill=Crimson,
    radius=.05
  }
]
  \begin{scope}
     \path[minor grid] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
     \path[major grid] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);

     \path[green circle] circle [];
     \path[red dot] circle [];

     \foreach \cRight in {0,...,15}
       \foreach \cDown[
         evaluate={\length=max(rnd*.9*minorGridStep,1.5\pgflinewidth)},
         evaluate={\angle=rnd*360}
       ] in {0,...,15}
         \draw[triangle 90 cap reversed-triangle 90 cap] ([shift=(\angle:-\length/2 pt)] \cRight/16*2-1+.0625,\cDown/16*2-1+.0625) -- ++ (\angle:\length pt);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to shrink an arrow in tikz?

Comment: @WangZhu It is, for fixed size, take a look at [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461) for scaling proportionally [Why can't I apply this decoration to a curve produced using the "to" path operation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89222)